How to modify orphan row due to break at large footnote that spans two pages?
The purpose of this attempt at a decent example is to illustrate an instance in which a lengthy footnote spans two pages such that the regular text stops at the line containing the footnote. The issue is that this line is also the last full line of the paragraph and a break at that point leaves an orphan line on the next page.
I've tried increasing/decreasing the size of the first page and/or the previous page, using \enlargethispage{...}, but the result is always the same, which is that the number of lines of the footnote content that appear on the first page changes and the break in the regular text is alway right at the line with the note.
This appears to make sense, of course; but is there a way to include the orphan row on the first page and push a row or two of the footnote content to the second page?
Thank you.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[12pt,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 letterpaper,
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in,
 marginparwidth = 1.25in,
 marginparsep = 0.25in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]\footnote{
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[6-12]
} a couple of orphan words.

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}


Footnote content runs to bottom of page and continues, ending on the bottom of following page.

ADDED AFTER ANSWER
I could not get the answer to work in the document and it appears to be due to there being additional text on the page above/before the paragraph having the footnote. Increasing the magnitude of the reduction in \addtolength{\dimen\footins}{-\baselineskip} to -5 make this new example "work". But why, when only one line of text is moving between pages in both examples? Thank you.
(David Carlisle answered this in a comment to his answer below. My document required  a reduction of 11 baselineskip, which were added back immediately after the paragraph.)
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[12pt,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 letterpaper,
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in,
 marginparwidth = 1.25in,
 marginparsep = 0.25in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom

\addtolength{\dimen\footins}{-5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[8][1-5]

\lipsum[1][1-5]\footnote{
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[6-12]
} a couple of orphan words.

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}


Are you familiar with the rule of thumb that footnotes are (often) best placed at the very end of a paragraph, rather than a few words befote the end? The rule of thumb would appear to do just fine in your example code.

@Mico Thanks. No, I wasn't aware of that. Nonetheless, I didn't write these words but am re-typesetting an old document, in which the footnote applies to the sentence that it follows and not the last one. In other words it makes sense where the author placed it in terms of flow of thoughts and would be a bit confusing if moved to the end of the paragraph.

If you're able to use LuaTeX, you can try lua-widow-control. Loading the package should probably be enough to fix this problem automatically. (disclaimer: I wrote that package).

@MaxChernoff Thanks. I just started to use LaTeX a couple months ago, and using Kile in Linux KDE. It appears that LuaTeX is supported in that tool but I've yet to try it. Thanks.

You can reduce the amount of space allowed for footnotes by one line. Globally (as here) or just locally for that page break, or set it globally and set it back again later.

\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[12pt,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
 letterpaper,
 includeall,
 twoside,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5in,
 textheight = 9in,
 marginparwidth = 1.25in,
 marginparsep = 0.25in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\raggedbottom

\addtolength{\dimen\footins}{-\baselineskip}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]\footnote{
\lipsum[2]\lipsum[6-12]
} a couple of orphan words.

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}


Thank you. This worked for the example but I could not get it to work in my document. So, I tried making everything in the preamble the same, and the example still worked. Finally, I tried adding more text about the start of the paragraph that has the footnote, and found that it requires reducing the length of the footnote by more than one baselineskip: five times as much. Do you know why , or am I doing something wrong? I added the revised example at the end of the post. I assumed one line of text would require the same change regardless of where the note is on the page. Thank you.

@Gary that's expected, perhaps I confused you by showing the setting as a subtraction. \dimen\footins specifies the amount of space from the bottom allowed for footnotes, if the footnote mark is already further down the page there is naturally less space available for footnotes  and so to have any effect on the page breaking you need to set it to a smaller value.

Thank you. I was thinking that the footnote space was being reduced from the page's current value.
